# Периодически вылетает DecoderInitializationException в ExoPlayer во время запуска видео

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

Запускаю одно и то же видео в плеере и он почему-то ведет себя по разному. Периодически вылетает исключение декодера. Запускаю видео в формате mp4 на устройстве Android 5.1. 
Stacktrace:

```
01-23 13:26:58.003 18664-18983/com.colorblind.uncolor.instagramtranslation E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.throwDecoderInitError(MediaCodecRenderer.java:380)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:367)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:507)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:479)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
 Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.MPEG4, Format(1, null, video/mp4v-es, -1, null, [396, 704, -1.0], [-1, -1])
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:367) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:507) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:479) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
 Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffffc3
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:590)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.configureCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:351)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:356)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:507) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:479) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Класс плеера:

```java
public class Player {

    private static final DefaultBandwidthMeter DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_METER = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    public Player(){

    }

    public SimpleExoPlayer getPlayerConfig() {
        return player;
    }

    public void releasePlayer(){
        if(player != null){
            player.release();
        }
        player = null;
    }

    private void getInstance(Context context){
        TrackSelection.Factory adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory
                = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_METER);
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
                new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory),
                new DefaultLoadControl());
    }

    public void initPlayerForWatchingSavedVideo(Uri uri, Context context){
        if(player == null){
            getInstance(context);
            DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(uri);
            final FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource();
            try {
                fileDataSource.open(dataSpec);
            } catch (FileDataSource.FileDataSourceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
                @Override
                public DataSource createDataSource() {
                    return fileDataSource;
                }
            };
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(fileDataSource.getUri(),
                    factory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);

            player.prepare(mediaSource);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    }
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ!